# Using gulp-babel gives Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: reactjs, gulp

I am using the following gulp.js file

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('bundle', bundle);

function bundle () {
     gulp.src('./src/*.jsx')
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
}

gulp.task('build', ['bundle']);
```

Before transpile "main.jsx" content

```
import React from 'react';
```

After Transpile, "js" files generated in the dist folder, has require('')

```
var _react = require('react');
```

while requesting for the page index.html

```
 <body>

    <div id="app" ></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined is shown in the console.

I know there is something wrong in the build task, but i am unable to figure out.

Answer (score 4):

In the browser, you can not use `require` API, so you need to somehow bundle your code, you have few options:

- Browserify
- Webpack
- Rollup

These module bundlers allow you to specify an 'entry' point and then bundle all the required modules together in a single file.

Similar questions that answer this problem:
[Gulp + babelify + browserify issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187695/gulp-babelify-browserify-issue)